# Is version 1.7.3 no longer supported?

Tags: ee1

Having trouble uploading .csv file into a template, as of just this week. We're running version 1.7.3. Is this version no longer supported?

Answer (score 0):

That's a really old version. It's not supported by ellislab anymore. My guess is that the hosting changed some stuff like the php version (because 1.x needs a really old php version too)